# Getting Cocos2d Box2d/Chipmunk templates to work w/Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode4, box2d, chipmunk

I've just followed the steps on the cocos2d site to install the latest xcode 4 project templates, however every time I try and create a Chipmunk/Box2d project it fails to build, stating there are ~26 issues.

I've read up on this a little and found that Xcode 4 change the way templates are handled which is causing the issue, but I haven't found what I need to do to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, I had the same issue as you but after a lot of searching I found a solution.

For some reason if your project name has a space in it then Xcode 4 doesn't link the Box2D framework in properly, thus giving you the 26 errors.

I recreated my project with a name without spaces and it compiled perfectly.

Comment: This didn't work for me!! Project is called "Accelerometer" and it loads with 15 errors!! Any more suggestions???